# set coordinates as center of imageview Android programmatically

Tags: android-layout, layoutparams

I have coordinates to align imageviews on these, programmatically. And right now images are being aligned but the image starts from this coordinate or I should say that the coordinate becomes its top left corner of my imageview and I want to make it center of my imageview. how to make coordinate center of imageview? Right now I'm doing this:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

float x_coordinate = 256;
float y_coordinate = 350;
    iv.setX(x_coordinate);
    iv.setY(y_coordinate);

    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mylayout.addView(iv);
```

Comment: I am not saying any of these options u asked. I want to make a coordinate,center of my imageview. For now by above written code that coordinate is being top left corner of my imageview.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find the simple one line solution but i solved my problem doing the following procedure. Here Place is my model class of which getX_Cord() and getY_Cord() returns the x and y coordinate of image, And you have to save an image in your drawable folder of which size you want to set on your screen in my case this is R.drawable.placeImage.

```
// display parameters
Point size = new Point();
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
display.getSize(size);
width = size.x;
height = size.y;

final Place place = roomPlace.get(i);

Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.placeImage);
int y = d.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2;
int x = d.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2;

placeImage.setX((place.getX_Cord() * width) - x);
placeImage.setY((place.getY_Cord() * height) - y);
```

May be someone gets with more appropriate solution but i solved my problem doing this.